# Where can I see the total size is the selected torrents in qBittorent?

Tags: windows-7, bittorrent, qbittorrent

After selecting several torrents in qBittorrent, where can I see the total size these torrents would take after the download is completed? (i.e., the sum of the "total size" column of the selected torrents)

[image]

I use qBittorrent v3.2.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.